# How to display label and data on pie chart using angular charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

Hi How to always display tooltips on pie chart using angular chart.

I'm trying using this part of code:

```
   $scope.options = {
            showToolTips: true,
            tooltipEvents: [],
            onAnimationComplete: function() {
                this.showTootip(this.datasets[0].bars,true);
            },
            tooltips: {
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
            }
        };
```

But it doesn't work. Here is my example of chart. https://jsfiddle.net/vz4qhqpw/115/

Comment: It should be `$scope.chart_options` no `$scope.options`

Comment: @BelminBedak, no $scope.options is working good try to change bg color or font size.

Comment: Tooltips doesn't show good with `$scope.options` https://jsfiddle.net/8d7xuswx/ .in fact I don't understand what issue you have and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @BelminBedak but I want them always there not on hover :)

Comment: I don't know what's really going on here, but I'm pretty sure that `onAnimationComplete` hook doesn't work, instead you should go with this https://jsfiddle.net/62zmatoc/ - just small hint, hope it would help you.